# Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource: Seeing UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

I have ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource configured via Spring. Everything is working fine. I am trying to add more strings in the resource bundle, however, I see UnknownFormatConversionException.

I want the output to be:
`Following filesystems are below threshold level (25%):/db`

My resource bundle has
`filesystemsBelowThreshold=Following filesystems are below threshold level {0}%:{1}`

However, above formatting does not work, it complains with 
`UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ')'.`
If I remove the round braces, it complains with 
`UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ':'.`
I tried escaping % with another %, as
`filesystemsBelowThreshold=Following filesystems are below threshold level {0}%%:{1}`, however, I get `UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ':'.`

Any idea how do I fix this?

Comment: I think = and : are special characters in properties file

Comment: @SRT_KP: That does not work. I changed to `filesystemsBelowThreshold=Following filesystems are below threshold level {0}%\:{1}`, however, I still get the same error, i.e. `UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = ':'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

And the properties file

```
filesystemsBelowThreshold=Following filesystems are below threshold level {0}%:{1}
```

And the test

```
        Object[] obj = {25, "/db"};
        String str= message.getMessage("filesystemsBelowThreshold", obj, null);
        System.out.println(str);
```

And the output

**Following filesystems are below threshold level 25%:/db**